# Как мне привязать картинку к курсору?

Tags: c#, unity3d, ui

Сделал Drag and drop систему. Есть баг. Когда жмякаю по элементу, который собираюсь перетаскивать, то он появляется не совсем там где мне нужно. При всем при этом это все происходит внутри прокручиваемой области. Вроде все должно работать как нужно, но по всей видимости из за этой прокручиваемой области все получается как то с большой погрешностью. В самой области элементы расположенны по GridLayoutGroup системе. Если я собираюсь перетащить правый элемент, то его копия смещается немного влево от курсора, если я левый элемент - то смещается вправо. Если же беру элементы по центру - то получаю практически идеальный захват...
В чем может быть проблема даже не могу представить. Обратите внимание, ошибка скорее всего в неверно заданном исходном значении спрайта, а именно в этой строчке кода:

```
RTdragObjPanel.anchoredPosition = eventData.position;
```

Здесь выложу весь основной код с захватом и переносом:

```
// Вот часть кода с захватом и переносом:
    public void OnBeginDrag(PointerEventData eventData) {
        dragObjPanel = new GameObject(spriteName, typeof(RectTransform), typeof(Image), typeof(BoxCollider2D), typeof(Rigidbody2D), typeof(InventaryDragAndDropElements));
        dragObjPanel.layer = 5;
        dragObjPanelTransform = dragObjPanel.transform;
        dragObjPanelTransform.SetParent(tParent);

        RTdragObjPanel = dragObjPanel.GetComponent<RectTransform>();
        RTdragObjPanel.sizeDelta = new Vector2(150f, 150f);
        RTdragObjPanel.localScale = Vector3.one;
        RTdragObjPanel.localPosition = Vector3.zero;
        RTdragObjPanel.anchoredPosition3D = Vector3.zero;

        BoxCollider2D bc2d = dragObjPanel.GetComponent<BoxCollider2D>();
        bc2d.size = new Vector2(25f, 25f);
        bc2d.isTrigger = true;
        dragObjPanel.GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>().gravityScale = 0f;

        RTdragObjPanel.anchoredPosition = eventData.position; // Здесь нужно что то другое присваивать, с той погрешностью, с которой элементы располагаются внутри другой системы отсчета...
        dragObjPanelTransform.GetComponent<Image>().sprite = Resources.Load<Sprite>("Sprites/Things/" + spriteName) as Sprite;
    }

    public void OnDrag(PointerEventData eventData) {
        RTdragObjPanel.anchoredPosition += eventData.delta / canvas.scaleFactor;
    }
```

[image: Иерархия папок]
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Отвечаю на собственный вопрос.
Какой код был ДО я уже выкладывал в своем вопросе.
Код который заработал как надо скидываю здесь.
Получается важно переместить якоря в нижний левый угол, потому что координата (0,0) канваса исходит от туда.

Далее есть 2 варианта:

1ый способ) Каждый кадр устанавливаем новую позицию, которая равна позиции указателя. (Этот способ мне показался максимально надежным). В этом случае в обработчике OnBeginDrag устанавливать позицию совсем не обязательно, а делать это в обработчике OnDrag.

2ой способ) В обработчике OnBeginDrag устанавливаем позицию курсора, а в OnDrag прибывляем к имеющейся позиции дельту изменения расстояния с прошлого кадра.

Оба варианта делим на canvas.scaleFactor чтобы это все работало одинаково для всех разрешений экранов...

```
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.EventSystems;
using UnityEngine.UI;

public class InventaryDragAndDropElements : MonoBehaviour, IBeginDragHandler, IDragHandler, IEndDragHandler {

    private Canvas canvas;
    private Transform tParent; // Родитель для перетаскиваемой области.
    private string spriteName;

    // Перетаскиваемый объект:
    GameObject dragObjPanel;
    Transform dragObjPanelTransform;
    RectTransform RTdragObjPanel;

    public void OnBeginDrag(PointerEventData eventData) {
        dragObjPanel = new GameObject(spriteName, typeof(RectTransform), typeof(Image), typeof(BoxCollider2D), typeof(Rigidbody2D), typeof(InventaryDragAndDropElements));
        dragObjPanel.layer = 5;
        dragObjPanelTransform = dragObjPanel.transform;
        dragObjPanelTransform.SetParent(tParent);

        RTdragObjPanel = dragObjPanel.GetComponent<RectTransform>();
        RTdragObjPanel.anchorMin = new Vector2(0f, 0f); // Обязательно меняем якоря в нижний левый угол !!!
        RTdragObjPanel.anchorMax = new Vector2(0f, 0f); // Обязательно меняем якоря в нижний левый угол !!!
        RTdragObjPanel.sizeDelta = new Vector2(150f, 150f);
        RTdragObjPanel.localScale = Vector3.one;
        RTdragObjPanel.localPosition = Vector3.zero;
        RTdragObjPanel.anchoredPosition3D = Vector3.zero;
        

        BoxCollider2D bc2d = dragObjPanel.GetComponent<BoxCollider2D>();
        bc2d.size = new Vector2(25f, 25f);
        bc2d.isTrigger = true;
        dragObjPanel.GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>().gravityScale = 0f;

        RTdragObjPanel.anchoredPosition = eventData.position / canvas.scaleFactor;
        dragObjPanelTransform.GetComponent<Image>().sprite = Resources.Load<Sprite>("Sprites/Things/" + spriteName) as Sprite;
    }

    public void OnDrag(PointerEventData eventData) {
        //RTdragObjPanel.anchoredPosition += eventData.delta / canvas.scaleFactor; // Эта строчка верная, но следующая более надежная.
        RTdragObjPanel.anchoredPosition = eventData.position / canvas.scaleFactor;
    }

    public void OnEndDrag(PointerEventData eventData) {
        Destroy(dragObjPanel);
    }

    void Start() {
        canvas = GameObject.Find("Canvas").GetComponent<Canvas>();
        tParent = canvas.transform;
        spriteName = GetComponent<Image>().sprite.name;
    }
}
```